# How can I solve this printing error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a code, which includes the following lines:

```
    #REBIN CUBE TO 10 MAS

        print 'Input PSF sampling = (%.1f, %.1f) mas' %(spax[0]/10.),spax[1]/10.) 
       if head['CDELT1'] != spax[0] and head['CDELT2'] != spax[1]:
           print ('Rebinning input datacube to %.0f mas (same as PSF generation scale)') % (spax[0]/10.)
          cube *= (head['CDELT1']*head['CDELT2']*1.E-6)
```

I get the following Syntax Error:

```
    line 141
        print 'Input PSF sampling = (%.1f, %.1f) mas' %(spax[0]/10.),spax[1]/10.) 
            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried adding parentheses, both sides, but nothing has worked.

Comment: you should read about difference between Python 2 and 3 in `print`: it was statement like `assert` in Python 2 but became a built-in function in Python 3

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing good,

```
print('Input PSF sampling = (%.1f, %.1f) mas' % (spax[0]/10.,spax[1]/10.) )
```

Should work.

There were two problems:

In python-3.x, print is always with parenthesis. The second problem is that there was an extra parenthesis in your arguments to display.

Have a lovely day.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaanks a bunch. You made it lovely.